# Layer dimensions in after effects

Tags: after-effects, post-production

How can I **find the dimensions in pixels** of a layer in adobe after effects.

Comment: do you mean whether if its a 2D or 3D layer?

Comment: @ProfessorSparkles No, I wan't to know how many pixels wide and how many pixels tall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the pixel dimensions of a layer you can use this expression:

> ```
> layer.sourceRectAtTime(t = time, includeExtents = false)
> ```
>
> **t**: the time index, in seconds. A floating-point value.
>
> **includeExtents**: true to include the extents, false otherwise. Extents apply to shape layers only, increasing the size of the layer
>   bounds as necessary.

This is only for AE version > 13.2 (CC 2014.2). See the announcement [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/aftereffects/2014/12/after-effects-cc-2014-2-13-2.html).

For earlier versions [this question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/13001/can-you-measure-the-width-of-a-character-in-an-ae-expression) is relevant, in the answers there is a link to an expression that achieves the same result, albeit a lot slower.

Comment: Thanks, sadly I'm still on CS6 D:, so I wont accepted it (But you earned an upvote), since I'm pretty sure that there *must* be a way.

Comment: edited with link for previous versions of AE.

Answer (score 7):

To find the pixel dimensions of a layer in AE,

Hit 's' that brings up scale,
then right-click Scale to bring up the **Edit-Value** dialog,

[image]

then set **units** to **pixels**.

[image]

Comment: When I first read this I thought you were saying that you could change the value in the scale numerical box to pixels, and I was all: "what?! I never knew that!". But then I tried it and realised what you meant. A good suggestion though.

Comment: This seems a lot simpler than the current accepted answer. I will need to verify it though. Also, what version of AE are supported?

Comment: Yes, if you just want to know the dimensions this is simpler. Doing it with an expression means you can use that value dynamically to drive other things. So it depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

You get the scale of the layer in the Transform property menu as seen below. The scale is in relation to the comp width and height if its solid or adjustment layer, for imported footage its in relation to the source width and height.
To get pixel values you just do a little math:

`(Comp or Footage width|height/100)*Scale = pixel dimension of layer`

When it comes to shape layer, the size of the shape is shown in the path menu unless its a custom shape, there is no easy built-in way to determine the bounding box of a custom path, you would need to write a script for that.

[image]

Comment: No, that is wrong, scale is relative to the scale of the layer, if I brought in a 200px * 200px image into an HD comp, by your formula it would be 192px by 108px.

Comment: oh right, I was only thinking of solids as the pixel value of footage is usually known. I edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: This answer still has an error. The scale is **always** relative to the layer, whether it's a solid, adjustment layer or external layer. If you make a 10 X 10 pixels solid or adjustment layer  in a 100 X 100 pixels comp the scale will still say 100%, *not* 10%.

Comment: Feel free to make an edit. Not sure how to word it better.